# how do i keep track of title changes for firefox in ubuntu?

Tags: python, bash

A lot of websites (like gmail, facebook) change the page title when a new notification arrives. For eg, when i get a new email my gmail page title changes to "Gmail - Inbox (1)". Is there a way to keep track of when this changes using bash or python ? Like a small code which runs in the background and keeps track of title changes in different tabs or tabs i specify it to ?

Comment: If it was window titles, you might have a chance of doing it generically, but with tabs, the answer is likely to be very browser-specific, and probably best implemented with a browser plugin.  Also, you might want to look for Gmail and Facebook monitors that don't rely on a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What operating system? For the title on Unix you can poll for the X Window title using Xlib.

Something like this:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.Xatom import WINDOW
display = Display()
root = display.screen().root
active_id = root.get_full_property(_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, WINDOW).value[0]
window = display.create_resource_object('window', active_id)
title = window.get_full_property(_NET_WM_NAME, UTF8_STRING).value
```

But this will only care of the title of the main Window, so you would have to run your facebook in a separate Window, so in your case a browser plugin makes more sense, but then you can't use Python or Bash.

Comment: Thanks. But i am looking to get the titles of tabs. There surely must be some place where firefox stores the titles of the tabs. Any idea how and where i can access it ?

Comment: @tapan: It's stored in memory, which is not accessible from other processes. You will have to write a Firefox extension, and hence you can't do it in Python or Bash. You can poll the sites, but that won't work for Facebook chat.

Comment: Thanks. I think i'll tinker about with the fb and gmail apis then. Seems like this method wont work out.

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to grab the browser window title is the wrong approach. Have a look at [Specto](http://specto.sourceforge.net/). This is a program that automatically checks mail accounts, websites, RSS feeds, etc. for changes in certain intervals, e.g. every 10 minutes, or every hour.

You can get Specto from the Ubuntu software repository, by the way.

Comment: specto looks like what i want. I'll test it out to see if it works. However, what i am looking to do is write something like specto rather than use it :D

Comment: Specto is Open Source and was written in Python, so you could look around in their code. Good luck if you want to write your own Specto clone, because that's not going to be easy ;-)